# How to make images on Twitter not cropped?

Tags: html, css, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

A design on Twitter has been really bothering me. On the main feed, all posts with images are cropped and if I want to look at the full image I have to click the post to see it. I want to change this. I wanted such that the full image appeared on the feed page itself.

So I started digging using the inspect tool. A `<div class="r-1adg3ll r-13qz1uu"/>` is where the problem lies. It contains this value

```
element.style {  
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;  
}
```

Its basically setting the image's height to be `0.5625 * (rendered-width)`. I need to change this padding-bottom value to be `(actual-height/actual-width)`. That way, the height of the rendered image will be become `(actual-height/actual-width) * (rendered-width)`.

For context, here's an image of a post in the feed which is cropped.
[image]

And here is the same post opened to show the full image.
[image]

So my question to all you wonderful frontend devs is, how do I do this for all images in the feed? Do I need to write a chrome extension? or can I write some code in the dev-console to make it happen for all images in the feed. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Can you add an image of the issue?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic, sure, lemme add a couple of images to add context to the question.

Comment: Tweaking Twitter web app is quite daunting task.  I'm fighting image crop by (ab)using fact  there are real transparent IMGs there and show them on hover: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/402913-twitter-com-un-trim-images-on-hover

Comment: @myf I see. I did find some extensions for zoom-over-hover, but that wont work for me because I plan to screen-capture big twitter threads for which I need the images to be expanded. Would it be difficult and complex to calculate this new padding value for each image and replace it in the <div>?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic , I added images